# Button not executing function when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, windows, button

I have a button and I want it to execute a function when I click it but for some reason it isn't working at all. I think there might be a problem with how I am linking the button to my js file. Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-us"></html>
   <head>
      <script src = "spotifybot.js" charset = "utf-8"></script>
      <title>Spotify Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id = "login" style = "width: 100px;height: 100px">Login To Spotify</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

And here's my js file:

```
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify());
const request = require("request");

function loginToSpotify()
{
   console.log("Here");
}
```

Both the files are in the same folder btw in case you thought that might be the problem.

**EDIT:** After checking the browser console (I thought I'd be able to check my visual studio console but obviously not), I found the error to be with the "require" keyword

Comment: I figured out the problem, I was looking at the wrong console. I'm getting an error now when running the javascript file saying "requrie is not defined" so that's why nothing was running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require is not defined and you don't want to execute your function when you set up the listener.

```js
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify);
//const request = require("request");

function loginToSpotify()
{
   console.log("Here");
}
```

```html
   <head>
      <script src = "spotifybot.js" charset = "utf-8"></script>
      <title>Spotify Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <button id = "login" style = "width: 100px;height: 100px">Login To Spotify</button>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify());
```

You either:

```
addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify);
```

or:

```
addEventListener('click', function() { loginToSpotify() });
```

Comment: I tried that at first and changed it to have the parentheses because it wasn't working. The error has to do with the "require" keyword

Comment: You can use `import request from 'request';`. It seems you need to babel it to run it on browser which do not support `require` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) should be a function.

You're invoking the `loginToSpotify()` function, which returns `undefined`. So, you're passing `undefined` instead of the actual function.

You have to change this:

```
.addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify());
```

to that:

```
.addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify);
```

---

Btw, `.addEventListener()` doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `undefined`), so your `loginButton` now has a value of `undefined`.

You can either do this:

```
document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify);
```

Or, if you want to store the button as well:

```
const loginButton = document.getElementById('login');
loginButton.addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify());
```

to:

```
const loginButton = document.getElementById("login").addEventListener('click', loginToSpotify);
```

since you need to give it a reference to a callback function and not the returned value of calling it which is undefined by default.

And I see you're using require, is it an Electron JS app, happy coding :)